# A client error happened - Drupal 8 REST API Post method

Tags: drupal, resources, drupal-8, rest

While i call Drupal 8 custom rest API post method, i am getting below error. please help to me resolve this i struggle last 4 days.

[image]

Comment: if i call service with get method working fine.

Comment: Check the Drupal logs for any errors. Debug with Postman and post more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also get the client error. I simply used the same path and added `?_format=json` at the end of the URL and it's working.

Comment: This worked perfect. It also works nice for xml format too with ?_format=xml

Answer (score 12):

You are missing a configuration on your view, please do the following:

Edit the view you are exposing your REST export > In the format section click on the Settings link > In the Accept Request formats check the JSON option > Click on the apply button > Save the changes to your view.

Now you should have the JSON response without adding the query "?_format=json".

Cheers!

Comment: This should be the accepted response